# Como fazer este relevo ao passar o mouse num JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

O tabuleiro é 500x500 e cada quadrado dele é 50px, assim as variáveis `NovaPosicaoX` e `Y` pegam sempre a borda do quadrado onde ta o ponteiro do mouse.

O problema é que o relevo só funciona nos quadrados da borda da janela, e quando passo o mouse, isso não vai mudando. Tem que tirar o mouse da janela e voltar pra atualizar.

```
ImageIcon tabuleiro = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("tabuleiro.png"));
JLabel v = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("vazio.png"))); 
//Imagem que quero fazer o efeito de relevo ao passar o mouse sobre t

JLabel t = new JLabel(tabuleiro);

//Aqui seria o código onde coloco as posições de cada JLabel...
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

double x = t.getMousePosition().getX();

double y = t.getMousePosition().getY();

int novaPosicaoX, novaPosicaoY;

novaPosicaoX = (int) x - (int)x % 50;

novaPosicaoY = (int) y - (int)y % 50;   

v.setBounds(novaPosicaoX-3, novaPosicaoY, 50,50);

v.setVisible(true);

}

Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
v.setVisible(false);
}
```

A área em vermelho não funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: a pergunta estava no comentário do codigo, editei agora

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom, seu código não é um [**exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](/help/mcve), e depende de fontes externas(imagens), então não consegui reproduzir a solução em cima do código apresentado.

Mas creio que a abordagem que segui abaixo possa ser adaptada ao seu código, se a intenção é simular relevo em JLabels:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;

/**
 *
 * @author diego
 */
public class MouseOverTabuleiro extends JFrame {

    JLabel[] labels;

    public void start() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));

        labels = new JLabel[16];

        for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            label.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
            label.addMouseListener(getMouseEvent());
            labels[i] = label;
            add(label);
        }

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private MouseAdapter getMouseEvent() {

        MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
                label.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 3, 3, Color.BLACK));
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
                label.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
            }

        };
        return adapter;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MouseOverTabuleiro().start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

E o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O segredo da abordagem é o uso da classe [**`MatteBorder`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/MatteBorder.html) para "simular" o relevo nos labels, alterando o tamanho das bordas inferior e direita quando o mouse estiver sobre este componente através do evento `mouseEntered`, e retornar os valores destas duas bordas para semelhantes às outras duas quando o mouse estiver fora,  através do evento de `mouseExited`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, sua resposta ajudou muito. E q coincidência, faço o msm curso que vc : D